# Why S4 logic should have kripke models with reflexive and transitive relations?

Tags: modal-logic, kripke-models

From [here](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/the+logic+S4%28m%29#relation_to_kripke_frames) and [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/S5_(modal_logic)#Kripke_semantics) you can see that in S4 modal logic we should have Kripke models **(S,R,V)** which have a relationship **R** on their set of states **S** so that **R** is reflexive and transitive on S!
I know that the set of axioms we obliged on our logic forces us to have our models this way but actually, I don't know how and why!

Comment: Do you understand what is meant when people say that $S4$ corresponds to reflexivity + transitivity?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Welcome to MSE!

It helps to think about what the bonus axioms are saying.

- Axiom $T$ says $\square \varphi \to \varphi$
- Axiom $4$ says $\square \varphi \to \square \square \varphi$

What do these conditions say on frames?

---

Let's start with $T$. We know that for *any* valuation we like, we need to guarantee that $\square p \to p$ holds at every world. That is, no matter what the valuation, if $w$ only sees $p$-worlds, then $w$ must be a $p$-world too.

First, it should be clear that reflexive frames have this property. Since $w$ sees itself, if every world $w$ can see is a $p$-world, then $w$ itself must be a $p$ world.

But now say you look at a frame that *isn't* reflexive. Then fix a world $w$ that doesn't see itself. Now look at the valuation where $w$ thinks $\lnot p$ and every other world thinks $p$. Then since $w$ doesn't see itself, $w$ must think that $\square p$ is true! So $w$ thinks $\square p$ and $\lnot p$, and axiom $T$ fails!

So the frames validating $T$ are exactly the reflexive ones.

---

Let's move on to $4$. This says that if everywhere I can get in 1 step is a $p$-world, then everywhere I can get in $2$ steps is a $p$-world too.

Again, it should be clear that transitive frames have this property. After all, the definition of transitivity is that anywhere I can get in multiple steps is somewhere I can already get in 1 step.

As a (fun?) exercise, can you show that any nontransitive frame *doesnt* have this property? You'll want to argue like we did before with reflexivity. Fix a nontransitive frame. Then you can find worlds $x, y, z$ with $xRy$, $yRz$, but $x \not R z$. Can you cook up a valuation which makes axiom $4$ fail on this frame?

---

I hope this helps ^_^

Comment: +1, beat me to it again!

Comment: <3 ${}{}{}{}{}{}$

Comment: Thank you very much! :))
But I still have a problem!
Suppose a model with two states, each of them has true value for proposition p for example and relation R is such that you can only change current state with the other one in your next move. So your model is not reflexive however it validates T!

Comment: This is something that you can get a better sense of from Noah's answer. But "validation" is a property of _frames_ not of _models_. We want to know that for _every_ valuation on your frame, $\square p \to p$ is true. You happened to find _one_ valuation for which it works, but there may be other valuations on your same frame which think $\lnot (\square p \to p)$. Indeed, since your frame is non-reflexive, there _must_ be one. Can you find such a valuation?

Comment: I guess now I get it!
Do you mean that frame is different from model?! I can guess from what you said that a frame is the relationship in a model. Am I right?!
I think in the frame that I described, if we choose one state for proposition p to be true and the other one to be false we have your answer, which is in fact two different valuations! Am I right?
And by the way thank you very much! :))

Comment: Exactly! You've got it! ^_^. A **Frame** is a set with a binary relation. A **Model** is a frame equipped with a valuation function! The soundness/completeness of a modal logic is always taken with respect to frames, and indeed the connection between logic and frame conditions is _very_ tight (as Noah's answer shows).

Comment: I know that it may be irrelevant to the question a little!
But I would be very much appreciated if you give me formal clean definition of SAT problem for S4!

Comment: I'd be happy to, but that's probably far enough afield to warrant a new question. Go ahead and ask it -- I'm pretty active in the logic tag, so I'll see it when you do (unless of course someone beats me to it)

Comment: (also -- if I've answered _this_ question, you should mark my answer as such. That way other users know where to spend their time ^_^ )

Answer (score 1):

HallaSurvivor's answer is absolutely right. Let me add a bit more, however, about the general context surrounding it.

The relevant connection between *modal axiom systems* and *Kripke frame properties* is very particular:

> **Definition**:
>
> - A Kripke frame $(W,R)$ **validates** a modal sentence $\sigma$ iff for *every* valuation $\nu$ the sentence $\sigma$ is true at every world according to $(W,R,\nu)$.
> - A class $\mathfrak{F}$ of Kripke frames **validates** a modal sentence $\sigma$ iff *every* frame in $\mathfrak{F}$ validates $\sigma$.

The precise theorem connecting $S4$ and the class of transitive and reflexive frames, then, is the following multi-part result:

> **Theorem**:
>
> - A frame $(W,R)$ validates every theorem of $S4$ iff that frame is reflexive and transitive.
> - If $\sigma$ is not a theorem of $S4$, then there is a reflexive and transitive frame not validating $\sigma$

**It is in this sense that "$S4\approx$ reflexive + transitive."**

In their answer above, HallaSurvivor proved the first bulletpoint (actually they proved more than that - they analyzed the role of reflexivity on its own and transitivity on its own). And this was the point relevant to your question.

The second bulletpoint is a bit more subtle. Basically, it says that $S4$ *completely captures* the nature of reflexive and transitive frames: there's nothing "missing" from $S4$ in this regard. So we really have a very tight connection between a modal theory ($S4$) and a frame property (reflexive-and-transitive)!

*(In more technical language, the first bulletpoint says that $S4$ is **sound** with respect to the reflexive-and-transitive frame semantics (right-to-left direction) and moreover this is the maximal frame semantics with respect to which $S4$ is sound (left-to-right direction), while the second bulletpoint says that $S4$ is **complete** with respect to the reflexive-and-transitive frame semantics.)*

---

It's separately worth noting that we can rephrase things in terms of **operators**:

- **Frames-to-theories**: Given a class of frames $\mathfrak{F}$, let $Th(\mathfrak{F})$ be the set of modal sentences validated by $\mathfrak{F}$.
- **Theories-to-frames**: Given a set of modal sentences $T$, let $Fr(T)$ be the set of frames validating every sentence in $T$.

We always have $Th(Fr(T))\supseteq T$ and $Fr(Th(\mathfrak{F}))\supseteq \mathfrak{F}$. However, in general these may be strict inclusions. The two-part theorem above can be reformulated as:

> Let $\overline{S4}$ be the set of theorems of $S4$ and let $\mathfrak{X}$ be the class of reflexive and transitive Kripke frames. Then $$Th(Fr(\overline{S4}))=\overline{S4}\quad\mbox{and}\quad Fr(Th(\mathfrak{X}))=\mathfrak{X}.$$

Think of this as saying that the connection between (the theorems of) $S4$ and the class of reflexive and transitive Kripke frames is as good as we could hope - there's no "loss of information" in replacing one with the other, in a precise sense.

(The term "[**Galois connection**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Galois_connection#Definitions)" is relevant here, and it's a good exercise to try and figure out in what sense the pair of operators $(Th,\mathfrak{F})$ forms a Galois connection.)

Comment: +1 -- excellent as always. I beat you to it only by writing less ;)

Comment: I've never actually seen this phrased as a galois connection before either... That's a really interesting remark ^_^